# Compare two lists for pairs and build new list that has no duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists. First comes PROJECTNUMBER and second PROJECTMANAGER. So data is "PROJECTNUMBER PROJECTMANAGER"

Lets assume that List number 1:

```
1234 John
3214 Jack
```

and list number 2:

```
1234 John
3214 Adam
```

in new List number 3 I need to have

```
3214 Jack Adam
```

I have two questions:

1. My current code gets stuck in infinite loop, providing ProjectNumbers :) What is wrong in my current solution?
2. How can actually achieve expected result in Linq query? for getting both persons as an output in Linq query? Do I need to use reverse join with Concat or there is simpler solution?

Here is my current code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MFiles.SearchDeliveryProjectsInMFiles();

        var ProjectsFromMFiles = MFiles.DeliveryProjectList.ToList();

        var ProjectsFromLiinos = MainProcess.GetMyJoinedResult().ToList();

        var output = (from ps1 in ProjectsFromLiinos
                      from ps2 in ProjectsFromMFiles
                      where !(ps1.HENKILONIMI == ps2.ProjectManager && ps1.TILAUSNRO == ps2.ProjectNumber)
                      select ps2.ProjectNumber).ToList();

        foreach (var ProjectNumber in output)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ProjectNumber);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: It's extremely unclear how you relate "1234 John" to the code provided. We cannot run that code, so you have to explain what is what and show the relevant types (classes, enums, etc). Also, it's impossible for the provided code to get into an infinite loop, at worst it's just printing one item for each `ps1, ps2` combination

Comment: Yeah, what does "1234 John" even mean? And why was that item removed completely, whereas the others seemed to be combined? Please produce a simple example that demonstrates the issue (i.e. create a custom class, populate two lists of items from the class, and show how "duplicates" should be combined), including expected output and actual output.

Comment: Just to amplify what @CamiloTerevinto points out, you have two lists of what?  What are the types you are talking about.  As far as I can tell from your question, you have two `List<string>`.  Your code includes column names.  And, from that code, I can't figure out what you are trying to do

Comment: Also, please don't use `var` in sample code when the type it's hiding is not obvious to those who aren't familiar with your code.

Comment: With the edits, it's not so bad anymore. The crucial piece missing is the map "1234 John" to your structures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is actually basic math

**List1 U List 2 - List1 n List2** will give you what you need

so basic demonstration

```
IList<string> strList1 = new List<string>() { 
    "John", 
    "Jack"
};

IList<string> strList2 = new List<string>() {
    "John",
    "Adam"
};


var res = strList1.Union(strList2).Except(strList1.Intersect(strList2));
res.Dump();
```

for your case, you need to write `IEqualityComparer<JoinedFandS>` in order to compare two two classes.

Comment: Thank you for this! It would be easy but then I am getting `CS1929 'List<JoinedFandS>' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Union<(string ProjectNumber, string ProjectManager)>(IQueryable<(string ProjectNumber, string ProjectManager)>, IEnumerable<(string ProjectNumber, string ProjectManager)>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<(string ProjectNumber, string ProjectManager)>'`

Comment: you need to convert it to IEnumerable.